# How do I get the tupledict object using model.getVars()?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

Gurobi allows you to create multiple variables at once using (for example):

```
x = model.addVars(2,3,vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

This returns a tupledict object of 6 binary variables that can be accessed like `x[0,2]`, `x[1,1]`, ... etc

However, when I use the command `x = model.getVars()` (in a callback for example) it returns a list of variables, instead of a tupledict. So, when I go to reference variable `x[0,1]` I get the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I have established all of my variables with respect to their tupledict keys, not list indices, so i have no idea which variable is which. Is there any way that I can ask the model to give me the tupledict instead of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Model.getVars() returns a list of all variables; it does not know about the Python tupledict structure. To save the tupledict x for a callback, add it to the Model object, ex: model._myxvars = x, then you can use it inside the callback function.